# What is the name of the limit that a function converges except for the set of measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Define $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in \{0,2,4,\dots\}$, $f(x) = -1$ if $x \in \{1,3,5,\dots\}$, and $f(x) = 1/x$ elsewhere. Then, $\limsup_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 1$, $\liminf_{x\to\infty}f(x) = -1$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty,\,x\notin\{0,1,2,\dots\}}f(x) = 0$. Is there a proper name of the limit $0$ that a function converges except for the set of measure zero?

Comment: I'd suggest "essential limit". See f.i. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126921/obtaining-functionals-on-l1-and-l-infty-by-extending-essential-limit

Comment: @mlc Thanks. The essential limit makes sense.